# Apache httpd Problem

Tags: apache, server, proxy, httpd

I am getting intermittent issues with my site. Pages often hang with huge loading times and sometimes fail to load.

The httpd error logs contain the following:

```
[Wed Feb 23 06:54:17 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 5871 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Feb 23 06:54:17 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 5871 for (*)
[Wed Feb 23 06:54:24 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 5872 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Feb 23 06:54:24 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Feb 23 06:54:24 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 5872 for (*)
[Wed Feb 23 06:59:15 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 5954 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Feb 23 06:59:15 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
```

The server is currently running with 800mb free memory, so it is not caused by lack of RAM.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Chris.

**EDIT**

The current number of httpd procceses is 11. This does increase as the error persists and can rise up to 25+.

I am running Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS).

Comment: To get any meaningful answers, you should add little bit more information about your setup: what proxy, what version of apache, what's running behind the proxy?

Comment: @Olli. Thank you for your response. I am running Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS). I was not aware I am usuing a proxy. I hope this helps. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Apache2 worker module, you can try finding something like

```
StartServers           2
MaxClients            50
MinSpareThreads       25
MaxSpareThreads       25
ThreadsPerChild       25
MaxRequestsPerChild  500
```

from your apache configuration file (may be for example `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`).

If you raise MaxClients, then you can serve larger amount of clients.

You should monitor your server load before making too dramatic changes. Good tools for this are for example `top`, `iotop` (for IO load) and [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for drawing nice system load graphs.

Comment: Hi Olli, thank you for your answer. I have tried the above suggestion and restarted httpd but the problem still remains and the same errors appear in the error log. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What is your httpd.conf mod_proxy config?  How many other servers does this proxy pass point to?  I have something that I think it similar to what you are doing as well, but I can't know for sure without seeing configs or knowing the setup.